# Getting Current time of day

Tags: java, time, calendar

```
public void getTime()
{
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.getTime();
    this.minutes = calendar.MINUTE;
    this.hours= calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY;

}
```

Given this code does the variable minutes and hours set to the current time in an integer value? it doesn't seem so is there something wrong?

Comment: what do you feel is wrong?

Comment: `Calendar.MINUTE` is a static field and a constant! Read the Javadoc to understand how to use Calendar: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: i feel like it doesn't actually give me my current time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this to get the Minutes, and Hour from the Calender instance of Current Day

```
this.minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
this.hours= calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

`Calendar.MINUTE` and `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` are constants, it only give the int value. Apply the int value to your calendar instance and get the Minute and Hour value.

Answer (score 2):

The [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class is intended to be used this way:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
this.minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
this.hours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

By the way, the line `calendar.getTime();` doesn't do anything since you are not saving the result of `getTime` in a variable.

I would also recommend to rename the method `void getTime()` since it is not a getter method (it doesn't return anything).

Answer (score 1):

it should be used like this

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
this.minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
this.hours=calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed `Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();` does set `calendar` to the current day. That bit of code is fine.

But `calendar.MINUTE` and `calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` are constant values from an *enumeration*. That's why you're getting odd results.

You need to supply the enumerator values as parameters to a *function*: for example

```
this.minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
this.hours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```